# How to I encode/decode User ID(int) into numeric format in 8 digit number

Tags: php, encryption

I want to encode user_id(it's always in inter) into numeric format upto maximum 8 to 10 digit number.

Like `User_id = 86` it will encode like this way `25413657(any numeric format )`

Comment: If you need to encode an int in int just write any formula for it. i.e  yourint = yourint*438989 and yourint=yourint/438989 for decode.

Comment: If you want more security use `hash` functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use decimal to binary if security is not the issue.

```
//86 to 8 bit binary
$bin = decbin(86)
$bin = substr("00000000",0,8 - strlen($bin)) . $bin;

echo $bin; //01010110

//$bin to dec i.e 86
echo bindec($bin); //86
```

OR

as also can use any of your own formula to convert.

OR

you can use PHP [hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php)